# R - Creating Variables With For-Loop

Tags: r, variables, for-loop

[this question is edited]

I want to simplify my question - I hope that will lead to understanding enough to answer the more complex one myself.

How can I create the variables a:i in R with a for-loop?

```
for(i in a:i) { "create variable [i]"

}
```

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: You should include a sample of `model_daten` to make this reproducible

Comment: model_daten has 1.2 milion rows and 50 columns. How should I do this? It is a dataframe.

Comment: Read the advice [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) on creating a minimal, complete, & verifiable example for R questions. Are all 50 columns of the same type? A sample of 3-4 should suffice. Are all rows similar in nature? Take the first 20 or so. Verify that your example works with the sample, paste it here using `dput()`, & describe the desired outcome based on that sample.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `assign`

```
for(I in 1:6) { 
      assign(letters[I], 1)
}
```

Output

```
 list(a,b,c,d,e,f)
[[1]]
[1] 1

[[2]]
[1] 1

[[3]]
[1] 1

[[4]]
[1] 1

[[5]]
[1] 1

[[6]]
[1] 1
```

Comment: This has been receiving downvotes. As far as I can tell, it is relevant to OP's question, so I'll leave it up. But if OP wants to clarify, I can revise or delete my answer. To downvoters, a comment would help, but no comments work too.